# MSbuild solution with referenced DLL from a project within the solution

Tags: compilation, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get our continuous integration server (cruise control .net) working with our solution. From cruisecontrol i call msbuild to build the solution and i'm running in some problems, let me explain the structure of the solution:

4 Projects:

- DataAccess
- BusinessEntity
- BusinessLayer
- (Project A)

Project A is the actual project with all the user forms etc.
This project has references to the other 3 projects.

When compiling in Visual Studio, everything works of course..
From what i understand is that MSBuild works quite different from VS.

When building project A with msBuilds i get the following error:

```
C:\CI\Project A\Source\Project A\General.vb(859,33): error BC30007: Reference   required to assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' containing the base class 'System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent'. Add one to your project. [C:\CI\Setra\Source\Project A\Project A.vbproj]]]></message>
```

The funny thing is that Project A has no reference at all to the mentioned assembly. But the referenced DLL's in project A do have.

When i compile the other projects (those that generate the DLL's) with msbuild, the build succeeds.

I have the feeling it has something to do with the way the DLL's are referenced in the main project, but i can't seem to figure it out..

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This blogpost](http://www.howstevegotburnedtoday.com/post/msbuild-cant-find-secondary-references), despite being quite old, should answer your question. Some more useful info on how to approach this problem can be also found [here](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Resolving-Binary-References-in-MSBuild.aspx).

In general, MSBuild has problems resolving secondary, ternary etc. references directly. More up to date article can be found [here](http://www.nsilverbullet.net/2012/02/17/automatically-resolving-secondary-assembly-references-with-msbuild-and-tfs-build/). I haven't tested this approach, though it seems quite good and easy to implement at the first sight:

> Paste the following code into the file before the last  tag:

```
<Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
    <!-- Redefine referencepath to add dependencies-->
    <ItemGroup>
        <ReferencePath Include="@(ReferenceDependencyPaths)"></ReferencePath>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. adding the code you mencioned to each of the projects solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

This may be the issue

> Project A is the actual project with all the user forms etc. 
>   it has **references to 3 DLL's which are created by the other projects**.

In Solution Explorer, right click References and add a new Reference.
Do not browse for the dependency under Assemblies, instead go to Projects, Solution, choose the DataAccess, BusinessLayer, and BusinessEntity projects.

Now remove the File references & save the project file.  When you rebuild, msbuild will detect these ProjectReference dependencies

Comment: The projects are referenced in this way, i didn't describe that too well.. updated my original question !